# What does iterator->second mean?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

In C++, what is the type of a `std::map<>::iterator`?

We know that an object `it` of type `std::map<A,B>::iterator` has an overloaded `operator ->` which returns a `std::pair<A,B>*`, and that the `std::pair<>` has a `first` and `second` member.

But, what do these two members correspond to, and why do we have to access the value stored in the map as `it->second`?

Comment: A `std::map` stores a *key* and a *value*.`map::iterator.second` refers to the *value*.

Answer (score 312, accepted):

I'm sure you know that a `std::vector<X>` stores a whole bunch of `X` objects, right? But if you have a `std::map<X, Y>`, what it actually stores is a whole bunch of `std::pair<const X, Y>`s. That's exactly what a map is - it pairs together the keys and the associated values.

When you iterate over a `std::map`, you're iterating over all of these `std::pair`s. When you dereference one of these iterators, you get a `std::pair` containing the key and its associated value.

```
std::map<std::string, int> m = /* fill it */;
auto it = m.begin();
```

Here, if you now do `*it`, you will get the the `std::pair` for the first element in the map.

Now the type [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) gives you access to its elements through two members: `first` and `second`. So if you have a `std::pair<X, Y>` called `p`, `p.first` is an `X` object and `p.second` is a `Y` object.

So now you know that dereferencing a `std::map` iterator gives you a `std::pair`, you can then access its elements with `first` and `second`. For example, `(*it).first` will give you the key and `(*it).second` will give you the value. These are equivalent to `it->first` and `it->second`.

Comment: Why don't they just use [0] and [1] (for "first" and "second") like everything else in programming?

Comment: @AdamCross Because `operator[]` has to return a specific type but `first` and `second` can have different types. On the other hand, `std::tuple` has a special helper function `std::get` for accessing its elements by index.

Comment: Supplements of official documents: [map](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map), under **Member types**, it has the `value_type`, which refers to [pair](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/), clearly you will see its member variables `first` and `second`.

Comment: Why didn't they just call it `key` and `val` or even `k` and `v` which is far more logical and easy to deduce rather than something as esoteric as first and second?

Answer (score 24):

The type of the elements of an `std::map` (which is also the type of an expression obtained by dereferencing an iterator of that map) whose key is `K` and value is `V` is `std::pair<const K, V>` - the key is `const` to prevent you from interfering with the internal sorting of map values.

`std::pair<>` has two members named `first` and `second` (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair)), with quite an intuitive meaning. Thus, given an iterator `i` to a certain map, the expression:

```
i->first
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
(*i).first
```

Refers to the *first* (`const`) element of the `pair` object pointed to by the iterator - i.e. it refers to a *key* in the map. Instead, the expression:

```
i->second
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
(*i).second
```

Refers to the *second* element of the `pair` - i.e. to the corresponding *value* in the map.

Comment: The words "key" and "value" would have been more intuitive than "first" and "second", which imply ordering.

Comment: @ahoffer lets overload it :D

Answer (score 2):

## Used for map and unordered map.

#### map stores the key-value pair where i->first is for key and i->second is reflecting value.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define long long int
using namespace std;
int32_t main(){
  map<int,int> m;
  m.insert({1,2});
  m.insert({2,4});
  for(auto i:m){
      cout<<"key - "<<i.first<<" "<<" Value - "<<i.second<<endl;
  }
}
```