# I am trying to create a method which returns a pair using pointer arithmetic howevever it givies an error?

Tags: c++, dictionary, data-structures, stl, std-pair

I am trying to return a pair using an iterator from a map called `map <int, vertex> nodemap`however I am running into an error which says: `error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::map<int, vertex>::iterator' (aka '__map_iterator<typename __base::iterator>') and 'int') std::pair<int, vertex> node = *(it + v);`

Below is my function code:

```
std::pair<int, vertex> Graph::getMap(int v)
{
  std::map <int, vertex>::iterator it = nodemap.begin();
  std::pair<int, vertex> node = *(it + v);
  return node;
}
```

I am assuming that pointer arithmetic is possible and a map is composed of pairs as mentioned in this [Stack Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451287/what-does-iterator-second-mean).

Thank your for your help!

Comment: Are you looking for the vth element in the map or for the node with key v?

Comment: The see GWW's answer. Just get the element with nodemap.find(v). std::map is an associative container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::map` returns a [bidirectional iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/BidirectionalIterator/), which does not support addition.  You can use `std::advance(it, v);`, however, I am not sure why you would want to increment a `map::iterator` like that.  If you want to retrieve the `vertex` with the key `v` you would use:

```
std::map <int, vertex>::iterator it = nodemap.find(v);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error come from this line:

```
std::pair<int, vertex> node = *(it + v);
```

`std::map::iterator` is [bidirectional](http://www.cplusplus.com/BidirectionalIterator) which means it can use `++` and `--` on it.

In order to use "`iterator + intValue`", the iterator should be a [Random Access](http://www.cplusplus.com/RandomAccessIterator) iterator. Which is not the case with `std::map`