# Does map store elements as std::pair?

Tags: c++, stdmap, std-pair, internals

Does std::map store elements as [std::pair](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair)? Iterating over map looks like this:

```
#include <map>
int main() {
    std::map<int, char> m;
    m[1] = 'A';
    m[2] = 'B';
    m[3] = 'C';

    std::map<int, char>::iterator it;
    for(it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); it++)
    {
       std::cout << "Key: "    << it->first;
       std::cout << " Value: " << it->second;
       std::cout << std::endl;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Why not just look at the implementation of your particular compiler.  Not all vendors use the same template.  The source code for templates is normally in the header file.

Comment: From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map :
"std::map is a sorted associative container that contains key-value pairs with unique keys.". In practical sense I would say: yes. In technical sense: no, std::map implementation just provides such iterator (but I'm not expert). I'm not sure what you're looking for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No, `std::map` doesn't *store* data as pairs, it just *exposes it* as pairs.** Although it's not forbidden to use `std::pair` in underlying storage.

In typical red-black tree implementation you need at least two pointers to children nodes on top of key and value stored (and probably a pointer to parent node, I don't really remember how RB tree worked, sorry). The underlying storage type is `std::map::node_type` (added since C++17), which is unspecified in standard (a.k.a. implementation specific).

---

Note that there is this clause (from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/node_handle)):

> For all map containers (std::map, std::multimap, std::unordered_map, and std::unordered_multimap) whose key_type is K and mapped_type is T, the behavior of operations involving node handles are undefined if a user-defined specialization of std::pair exists for `std::pair<K, T>` or `std::pair<const K, T>`.

It suggests that storing data in *node-handle* type as `std::pair` is definitely allowed by standard (and implementation may assume that `std::pair` behaves exactly as expected).

Comment: Here it is said that type of elements is std::map is std::pair<const X, Y>: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15451409/7101138. Is this then incorrect?

Comment: @michalt38 For for almost every use, the approximation that `std::map` stores objects of type `std::pair` is good enough. You insert and read data always as `std::pair`. In practice, data is stored in nodes, which contain `std::pair` (or just key and value as they are) and some pointers.

Comment: But can we say that type of elements in std::map is std::pair?

Comment: @michalt38 Yes, the type of elements in `std::map` would be `std::pair` (and those are stored internally in unspecified node class).

Comment: How does `std::map::node_type` store `std::pair<K, T>` yet the map is still able to expose pointers to `std::pair<const K, T>`?

Comment: @user1687327 It's a possibility, but gcc for example [stores `std::pair<const K, T>` in map's node_type](https://wandbox.org/permlink/y9t6qY2PoFNVw1pD). I suppose an implementation could get away with storing `std::pair<K, T>` and casting it every time it's returned (possibly in some UB involving way), but I can't think of any advantage of using that over `std::pair<const K, T>` off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is yes.

From `[map.overview]`, a `map` has a `value_type` of:

```
using value_type = pair<const Key, T>;
```

`[unord.map.overview]` has the same `value_type` as well.

---

Edit: as Yksisarviven states, these still needs to be stored inside a `node_type` of some sort, which is *unspecified* in the C++17 standard.

Answer (score 1):

From [std::map::extract](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/extract) I would conclude that it stores it as std::map::node_type. What that might be in practice is implementation specific. Researching my GCC 9.3 implementation yields:

```cpp
  template<typename _Val>
    struct _Rb_tree_node : public _Rb_tree_node_base
    {
      typedef _Rb_tree_node<_Val>* _Link_type;

#if __cplusplus < 201103L
      _Val _M_value_field;

      _Val*
      _M_valptr()
      { return std::__addressof(_M_value_field); }

      const _Val*
      _M_valptr() const
      { return std::__addressof(_M_value_field); }
#else
      __gnu_cxx::__aligned_membuf<_Val> _M_storage;

      _Val*
      _M_valptr()
      { return _M_storage._M_ptr(); }

      const _Val*
      _M_valptr() const
      { return _M_storage._M_ptr(); }
#endif
    };
```

This means in my implementation there is a _Val = std::pair contained in the node, i.e. yes, it stores std::pair, but wrapped in a node.