# C++ Assertion Failed: cannot increment value-initialized map/set iterator

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, containers, erase

I have been doing some training in C++, and last time I tried to run my code on another computer. There, I build in debug, and the execution stopped due to an assertion failed. I am manipulating containers, and when I use map, it seems removing an element is not possible. The removeItem() methode is triggering the assertion, but I could not get why.

Main:

```
int main()
{
    // Exercice 4.1   Map and strings
    std::list<std::string> list = {"eggs", "milk", "sugar", "chocolate", "flour"};
    CMapStrings mapStrings;
    mapStrings.print();
    mapStrings.addItem(list);
    mapStrings.print();
    mapStrings.addItem("coffee");
    mapStrings.print();
    mapStrings.replaceItem("sugar", "honey");
    mapStrings.print();
    mapStrings.removeItem("milk");  //buggy
    mapStrings.print();
    std::cout << std::endl; 
}
```

Hpp:

```
class CMapStrings
{
public:
    CMapStrings();

    void print();

    void addItem(std::string f_item);

    void addItem(std::list<std::string> f_items);

    void removeItem(std::string f_item);

    void removeLastItem();

    void replaceItem(std::string f_previousItem, std::string f_nextItem);

private:
    std::map<int, std::string> m_shoppingList2;
};
```

Cpp:

```
CMapStrings::CMapStrings()
{
}

void CMapStrings::addItem(std::string f_item)
{
    m_shoppingList2.insert(std::pair<int, std::string>(m_shoppingList2.size(), f_item));
}

void CMapStrings::addItem(std::list<std::string> f_items)
{
    for (std::uint32_t i = 0; i < f_items.size(); i++)
    {
        auto l_front = f_items.begin();
        std::advance(l_front, i);
        m_shoppingList2.insert(std::pair<int, std::string>(i, *l_front));
    }
}

void CMapStrings::removeItem(std::string f_item)
{
    for(auto it = m_shoppingList2.begin(); it != m_shoppingList2.end(); it++)
    {
        if(it->second == f_item)
        {
            m_shoppingList2.erase(it->first);
        }
    }
}

void CMapStrings::replaceItem(std::string f_previousItem, std::string f_nextItem)
{
    for(auto it = m_shoppingList2.begin(); it != m_shoppingList2.end(); it++)
    {
        if(it->second == f_previousItem)
        {
            it->second = f_nextItem;
        }
    }
}

void CMapStrings::print()
{
    std::cout << "shopping list size (map): " << m_shoppingList2.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << m_shoppingList2 << std::endl;
}
```

[image]

Comment: What line of your code does this occur on? If you don't know use the "Stack Frame" combo box on the debug toolbar to switch to your code.

Comment: `m_shoppingList2.erase(it->first);` probably causes the problem. erase returns an iterator to the item after the erase. Related: [https://www.techiedelight.com/remove-entries-map-iterating-cpp/#:~:text=The%20idea%20is%20to%20iterate,next%20element%20in%20the%20sequence.](https://www.techiedelight.com/remove-entries-map-iterating-cpp/#:~:text=The%20idea%20is%20to%20iterate,next%20element%20in%20the%20sequence.)

Comment: `std::cout << m_shoppingList2 << std::endl;` looks interesting. Does MSVC really have an `operator<<` overload for `std::map<int, std::string>`?

Comment: Yes exactly, I also found that:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451287/what-does-iterator-second-mean

Thanks Vlad from Moscow. Actually, I wanted to remove this question, because it was not that complicated, but people are on fire this evening, already several answers.

Comment: Nice catch Ted Lyngmo, I forgot to add these lines. So no, MSVC does not have this.

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& f_out, const std::map<int, std::string> f_value)
{
    for (auto const& value: f_value)
    {
        f_out << value.first << ":" << value.second << " ";
    }
    return f_out;
}

Comment: One question remains though. Why does this code works in Release mode? I have the answer, but still don t get WHY I get a assertion here...

Comment: *Why does this code works in Release mode?* -- Your program is not working in release mode.  Release mode doesn't have the checks that debug mode has, thus your program is exhibiting undefined behavior.  Your program may work now, not work tomorrow, work on your computer but break on another computer, etc.  Your program is still broken, regardless if it's running in release mode or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite this for loop

```
for(auto it = m_shoppingList2.begin(); it != m_shoppingList2.end(); it++)
{
    if(it->second == f_item)
    {
        m_shoppingList2.erase(it->first);
    }
}
```

the following way

```
for(auto it = m_shoppingList2.begin(); it != m_shoppingList2.end(); )
{
    if(it->second == f_item)
    {
        it = m_shoppingList2.erase(it);
    }
    else
    {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Pay attention to that this statement

```
std::cout << m_shoppingList2 << std::endl;
```

does not make a sense if you did not define the `operator <<` for objects of the type `std::map`.

And this loop

```
for (std::uint32_t i = 0; i < f_items.size(); i++)
{
    auto l_front = f_items.begin();
    std::advance(l_front, i);
    m_shoppingList2.insert(std::pair<int, std::string>(i, *l_front));
}
```

is inefficient. You could use the range-based for loop for example like

```
int i = 0;

for ( const auto &s : f_items )
{
    m_shoppingList2.insert(std::pair<int, std::string>( i++, s ) );
}
```